# LISP How can I associate a lambda function to a name/symbol to call it later?

Tags: lisp, lambda

As the title says I want to give my lambda function a name to call it later in my code.

But the name that I want to associate it to is a variable. What can I do?

```
(defparameter funct-name 'addone)
 funct-name = (lambda (x) (x+1))
```

So my call must be like this:

```
(addone 3)
```

`funct-name` is a variable that contains the name that I want to give to my lambda function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(setf (symbol-function funct-name) (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))
```